# How to forward constructor arguments for class template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Consider a sort of default `Bar`:

```
struct Bar
{
};
```

and a specific case of a `Bar`, `MyBar`, which has a constructor that requires an `int`:

```
struct MyBar
{
    MyBar(int n){}
};
```

I then have a class that uses a `Bar`:

```
template<class ThisBar = Bar> struct Foo : ThisBar
{
    Foo(double){}; // Construct the 'Foo' from a 'double'
};
```

A snag though is that if I want a `Foo<MyBar>` I need to be able to construct the `MyBar`:

```
Foo<MyBar> f(1.0, 1);
```

where the `int` is used to construct the `MyBar`. My question is how do I write this constructor, so the below compiles in C++17?

```
int main()
{
    Foo<MyBar> f(1.0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Which constructor should be picked if there are many?

Comment: There won't be any more than one constructor in 'MyBar'.

Comment: copy and move constructors?

Comment: Let's assume they can all be safely deleted.

Comment: I would consider changing the title: This has nothing to do with "template specialization" as far as I can tell.

Comment: @joergbrech: I'm wondering if this is too advanced for me to judge the title. Would you lend a hand?!

Comment: Hmmm, I dunno. Maybe "How to forward constructor arguments for class template"? I am not good with titles. But "template specialization" explicitly refers to another technique, so it may be misleading here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a templated constructor and forward the template arguments:

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct Bar
{
};

struct MyBar
{
    MyBar(int n){}
};

template<class ThisBar = Bar> struct Foo : ThisBar
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    Foo(double, Ts&&... ts)
     : ThisBar(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) 
    {};
};

int main()
{
    Foo<MyBar> f(1.0, 1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WjfosqYqn

Comment: Thank you very much! Out of interest, is it possible for the `Foo` constructor to have a default argument too like `Foo(double, int n = 0, Ts&&... ts)`? I simplified that in the question. For now I use an overloaded constructor with `n` missing in the argument list. That's possibly all I can do right?

Comment: @P45Imminent A default argument to an unknown base class will be a bit odd. The default argument should preferably be made default in the base class instead.

Comment: I think adding a default argument to Foo might be a bit dangerous. You can't add it at the end of the parameter pack and adding it in the beginning might lead to ambiguities, or at least unintuitive behavior (is the passed int the first parameter of the parameter pack and shall be forwarded to `ThisBar` or should it be used for the defaulted parameter of `Foo`?

Comment: Here is a workaround that might work for you: You define a proxy class `Foo::Init` with the arguments you want to pass into the `Foo` class, including default arguments. Then the templated `Foo` constructor gets a required `Foo::Init` instance as first argument. https://godbolt.org/z/cq9axsWze

Answer (score 5):

Use a templated constructor and forward the arguments

```
template<class ThisBar = Bar> struct Foo : ThisBar
{
    double val;

    template <typename... Ts>
    Foo(double x, Ts&&... args): ThisBar{std::forward<Ts>(args)...}, val{x}{}
};
```